# I2S Fundamentals

Tags: audio, i2s

I'm trying to get a good understanding of the I2S protocol for a project I'll be working on. My current goal is to take a 24bit, 2 channel .wav file with known, repeating bytes (ex: x00/x00) and view those bytes being sent over the I2S data bus with my scope. For this project I'm using a TI PUREPATH-CMEVM evaluation board paired with a TI TAS5733LEVM evaluation board (This is a stereo open loop digital input audio power amp with EQ). I'm using some TI provided software to send data over the I2S bus. The wave file I'm playing contains only 0's in the data chunk, but when I probe my I2S line I see (seemingly) random 1's and 0's being clocked in. I was hoping to ask the community if I'm interpreting the I2S protocol incorrectly, as I thought the data from the wave file would be send MSB first in the signed 2's complement form it's stored (so all zeros in my case).
     Here's a screenshot of my wave file and wave file header, just to show my wave file is setup correctly.
[image: Wave File Header]
[image: Wave File Data]

Here's a few screen caps of the 5733L's documentation and which pins I'm probing, just to show I'm looking in the right place.

[image: 5733L Pinout]

All the supporting hardware is supplied by TI on the eval board, so I believe my setup is correct. If anyone has any suggestions/ questions about my setup please let me know what I can clarify. I believe my confusion is in the protocol, not necessarily how the audio circuit is set up.
     The next few pictures are what I'm actually seeing on my scope. Green is the left/right clock, blue is the bit clock, yellow is the actual data (SDIN pin on the 5733L).

[image: Close up of I2S]
[image: far shot of I2S]

You can see from the zoomed out view of a few audio samples the bits being clocked in don't seem to follow any sort of pattern even though every byte being sent is the exact same. My question is for those with knowledge of I2S, if my audio file is populated with only zero's, do I expect to see only zeros? I could take pictures of zoomed in audio frames but every frame is different so I didn't know if it was of value to my question.

Comment: Surely there is a reference on I2S out there somewhere.  What does the protocol document say is supposed to happen?

Comment: https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/I2SBUS.pdf provides most of what you could need.

Comment: It looks like OP actually _did_ a research before asking the question. And the actual observed data does not look like the one expected per those documents.

Comment: @ OP: so, what DO you get on the data line? Could that be some noise or bad wiring? And what is exactly "my chip"?  How do you convert that .wav into I2S? Your setup is not clear from the description.

Comment: If you could add a visual representation of your waveforms, pointing out the discrepancies from what you expect, it would be helpful.

Comment: @Maple I updated my question to make it more clear what my problem is. I added a few screenshots of what I'm seeing on my scope, but every audio frame has different bits in it so I didn't know which one to focus on. I believe the integrity of the audio circuit (wiring etc) is good because I'm using a TI evaluation board. I did read through the I2S documentation and interpreted it such that if my audio file contains all 0's that only 0's would be sent across the I2S bus. I'm hoping to find someone knowledgeable of I2S to tell me if that interpretation is correct. Thank you!

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis I added a few screenshots of what I'm seeing, they don't specifically point out discrepancies in actual vs expected but I was expecting only zero's on the data line.

Comment: @hooky9 I hope there is someone here with actual knowledge of I2S to help you, because that someone is not me. Just couple theories: the info on I2S is flaky, sometimes it is suggested that actual bit stream is PCM (there are some hints to that in S5733L datasheet too). Now, some PCM formats have frame sync patterns, frame and sub-frame counters etc. So, not just digitized amplitude (or 0, in your case) as one would expect. Second, there could be data size mismatch. I2S supposed to pad the remaining bits with 0, but what if it does not and PPCMB sends e.g. 32bit with garbage at the end?

Comment: @Maple Thank you for your thoughts! that's definitely a good route to explore, I was pretty stumped with out any leads.

Comment: Also, do you have speakers connected and did you try playing something _with_ sound? The configuration menu in user guide is weird. What if you think you are playing your .wav but actual input is connected to something else (like coax) and picking up noise?

Comment: @Maple I've played known audio over a speaker, I don't see any noise when no audio is playing. There are 32 bit clocks for each channel even though I'm sending 24 bit audio. My understanding of the protocol is this is okay and it should be padded with 0's like you said. The stray 1's appear during and after the first 24 bits of the sample. Your suggestion to look at different PCM formats has been very enlightening, it seems the problems that different PCM formats solve (discerning individual bits and samples) are addressed by I2S's LRClCK and Bitclock so I'm not certain how they might relate.

Comment: @Maple Thank you for taking such an in depth look for me into the problem for me. I'm pretty new to electronics and I just don't have the scope to even know what to google haha

Comment: I wish I could help more. But I am really interested how this turns out. I2S is popping up everywhere nowadays

Comment: Was looking for something else and stumbled upon [this](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/presentation/70e1/d24cd92bf3bfe8fd0a9b4fdc000e465c9a73.pdf). Note on p3 they call PCM "one of the supported I2S standards ... with frame synchronization". So, to answer your earlier question, it seems manufacturers come to think of original Philips I2S specification as more like "transport layer", allowing them to choose what byte stream is actually being transferred. So, it could be PCM what you are seeing after all.